# Follow the div with a jquery function with mousedown, mousemove, mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna make a jquery function that "follow the div when it is on mousedown" - So the div on my page follows the cursor, as the mouse moves, when the mouse button is down.

and when the mouse button is up the div stay in the last position the mouse down was.

```
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var posX, posY;
    $(document).on('click', mueve);
    function mueve (e) {
        posX = e.pageX - 20;
        posY = e.pageY - 20;
        $('.item').animate({left: posX, top: posY})
    }
</script>
```

css:

```
.item{
    background: #bbb;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: i actually have what is in that question and what i want is a little bit diferent but i cant figure out how to make it.

Comment: Okay. It would be helpful if you noted that and if you could post your code.

Comment: <script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var posX, posY;

$(document).on('click', mueve);

function mueve (e) {
    posX = e.pageX - 20;
    posY = e.pageY - 20;
    $('.item').animate({left: posX, top: posY})
}

Comment: that is my code but is not closer for what i want.

Comment: .item{
    background: #bbb;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 0; top: 0;
}

Comment: what i actually need is and example or a real idea.

Answer (score 1):

Boom, check this out: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stA8K/1/).

Here's the javascript:

```
var posX, posY, clicked = false;
function mueve (e) {
    clicked = true;
    posX = e.pageX - 20;
    posY = e.pageY - 20;
    $('.item').animate({left: posX, top: posY});
}
$(document).on('mousedown', mueve);
$(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    clicked = false;
});
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if (clicked) {
        $('.item').stop(true, true);
        mueve(e);
    }
});
```

What I did was: when you click down, you change the variable `clicked` to true, so when you move the mouse it will move the div with class 'item'. Also, you have to clear each queued animation before updating positions.

Comment: If the parent div contains another child div having the word `click me` such that it looks like the mouse is always over that text but the whole parent div moves with it, how to modify that? I tried with adding the `.item` in the child div but only the child moves not the parent div as a whole?